# Does Wonka (2023) contradict the original Roald Dahl books in any way?

Tags: charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory, willy-wonka, wonka-2023

The new movie *Wonka* is clearly based on references in *Charlie and the Chocolate Factory*, most notably the names of the Chocolateers.

According to [Screenrant:](https://screenrant.com/is-wonka-timothee-chalamet-based-on-roald-dahl-book/)

> As far as the story is concerned, Wonka is a new, original work that is not based on any Roald Dahl book. The film is a freestanding interpretation of the chocolate maker's origin story rather than a remake of a specific tale, taking inspiration from Dahl's novels but having the character face circumstances imagined from scratch. Aside from minor references to the book version of Wonka's past, such as his famous hunt for flavors in the rainforest, the 2023 movie does not stage events that are featured in any of Dahl's books.

That said, does the prequel contradict the two books in any way, or is it perfectly faithful to the little detail that is there?

I'm not including minor details such as the color of the Oompa Loompa's skin, which have varied based on editions of the books.

Answer (score 5):

In short, there's practically nothing in the books that conflicts with Willie Wonka's backstory in *Wonka* (2023) or *Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory* (1971). In brief, we learn, he created a factory, his enemies stole his secrets, he fired all his workers, his factory reopened (a few years later) *under mysterious circumstances* and that pretty much brings us up to the present day.

In the novel he appears to use the interlude between the factory closing and the factory re-opening to import a [slave workforce](https://www.humanrights.unsw.edu.au/sites/default/files/inline-images/slavery_0.jpg), whereas in the Wonka film he has already encountered an Oompa-Loompa (Lofty, AKA Shorty-pants) at the outset of him becoming a factory owner. That's really the only minor discontinuity.

> The cacao bean is chocolate. I myself use billions of cacao beans
> every week in this factory. And so, my dear children, **as soon as I
> discovered that the Oompa-Loompas were crazy about this particular
> food,** I climbed up to their tree-house village and poked my head in
> through the door of the tree house belonging to the leader of the
> tribe. The poor little fellow, looking thin and starved, was sitting
> there trying to eat a bowl full of mashed-up green caterpillars
> without being sick. “Look here,” I said (speaking not in English, of
> course, but in Oompa-Loompish), “look here, if you and all your people
> will come back to my country and live in my factory, you can have all
> the cacao beans you want! I’ve got mountains of them in my
> storehouses! You can have cacao beans for every meal! You can gorge
> yourselves silly on them! I’ll even pay your wages in cacao beans if
> you wish!"

That being said, Wonka could easily be using hyperbole here. He may have decided to travel to Loompaland after firing his non-slave employees and *as soon as he realised that he needed some more biddable workers for his factory.*

---

Given that you've said you're not interested in small continuity changes, I'm almost hesitant to point out that Wonka consistently sports a small beard in the books, but not the films.

> ‘They must have,’ answered Grandpa Joe, ‘because soon after that,
> Fickelgruber’s factory started making an ice cream that would never
> melt, even in the hottest sun. Then Mr Prodnose’s factory came out
> with a chewing-gum that never lost its flavour however much you chewed
> it. And then Mr Slugworth’s factory began making sugar balloons that
> you could blow up to huge sizes before you popped them with a pin and
> gobbled them up. And so on, and so on. And **Mr Willy Wonka tore his
> beard and shouted, “This is terrible! I shall be ruined! There are
> spies everywhere! I shall have to close the factory!”’**

Comment: Without dismissing the considerable racism involved in the depiction of the Oompa-Loompas, it does not look like Wonka is enslaving them. He does not force them to come with him, but rather asks them to, offers them employee benefits that by all appearances he does give them, and he does not say that they *must* take their payment in cacao, but only that they can if they want to (which arguably and bizarrely, shows some kind of cultural competency, since he does not assume that what his culture values is what they would want to receive as payment).

Comment: That said, while the situation described is not slavery, I concede that there are elements that show conceptual consonance with elements of actual historical slavery.

Comment: Or at least some form of indentured servitude where people are brought to a strange place to work, and then their source of income, housing, and such are entirely dependent on the company. They're free to leave... but where would they go?

Comment: @Adamant - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-nUz92rZ1V4

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It's basically like the exploitation of foreign factory workers that  occurs right now (and in fact occurred even more at the same time as chattel slavery in the Americas). Pretty bad, but not the same as slavery. Indentured servitude, on the other hand, though historically distinguished from slavery, basically *was* what we would consider slavery (but with a limited term and neither hereditary nor racist, which differed from the chattel slavery common in the Americas).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Also they're in the country illegally.

Comment: {nods} You could at least (theoretically) work off your balance, although company towns being what they are, it was hard to not have your wages barely cover the cost of living there. But it was often posited as the same thing, bringing the people to a land where they could thrive, in exchange for working off the cost of passage.

Comment: @Valorum: True. I doubt he arranged work visas for them. And it does add the same wrinkle that we still see today with women smuggled across the border for prostitution, them also being trapped by knowing that going to the authorities means being charged with a crime and possibly being imprisoned.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - You're entirely correct in the historical context. In this fictional context, though, it is not by any means suggested that Wonka charged them anything for transportation, nor that they were in the country illegally (maybe he *did* get them work visas—it's not the kind of thing the rather whimsical book would dwell upon).

Comment: @Adamant - Nobody knew that they were there, including the authorities and local community. ->"*‘So I shipped them all over here, every man, woman, and child in the Oompa-Loompa tribe. It was easy. I smuggled them over in large packing cases with holes in them, and they all got here safely."*  / / / "*who is Mr Wonka using to do all the work in the factory?’ ‘Nobody knows, Charlie.’*"

Comment: @Valorum - I admit that does lend credence to the notion that he did not get them work visas, because he was clearly trying to hide their arrival from his competitors' spies at the *least*, so why not from the government? Although, again, it's not even the sort of thing the book would even think to mention one way or another, so it's not definitive. Note that "nobody knows" means "I don't know and neither does anyone on the street whom I talked to" not "Oh, yeah, I talked to my good friend the Home Secretary the other day and they said there was no record of any arrivals of workers."

Comment: But I agree that there's more than enough there to make an argument that they did enter illegally defensible. Like I said, looking at the pure facts, Wonka simply offered the Oompa-Loompas a highly mutually beneficial work agreement and followed through—but all the *trappings* of that agreement are heavily redolent of industrial exploitation at the least.

Comment: The worst of it is, Wonks uses the Loompas in his cruel and inhuman  experiments. Just how many perished in the chewing gum trials?

Comment: This conversation shows a other disconnect from the books - Wonkas personality seems to undergo a major change.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - His relationship with his workforce would result in his arrest for slavery and/or exploitation. Not just by modern standards, but also by the standards of 1964